# How to perform multi line search in Eclipse?

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, multiline

I wanted to search all the for loop within the for loop condition in my code.I have created regrex for that.

```
for?\(.*?;.*?;.*?\).*\s*for?\(.*?;.*?;.*?\)
```

This works for code like :

```
for(int i=0; i<StartTags.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<StartTags.length; j++){
```

but doesn't work for

```
for(;;) 
    {
        somecode;
            for(;;)
            {
                someOtherCode;
            }
    }
```

what should I add in regrex to make it work ?

I want to put some regrex instead of "`.*\s*`" so it will search multiline.

```
for?\(.*?;.*?;.*?\).*\s*for?\(.*?;.*?;.*?\)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can simplify your regex to:

```
for?\(.*;.*;.*\).*\s*for?\(.*;.*;.*\)
```

You see ".*" means: **any** occurrence of any char. Adding a "?" means: at least one time. **any times** one time ... as said: doesn't make sense.

But beyond that: I simply advise to **separate** your two cases.

Beyond that: your current pattern looks for

1. for construct
2. whitespaces
3. for construct

And as you could have noticed yourself - the **multiline** part is working fine with that. Your current pattern already matches two lines fine. But of course it can **not** match your second example. Because your second represents

1. for construct
2. whitespaces
3. somecode
4. whitespaces
5. for construct

In order to account for that, lets look at this:

```
for?\(.*;.*;.*\).*\s*.*\s*for?\(.*;.*;.*\)
```

In other words: for **each** line between those for constructs, you need **one** `.*\s*`

SO, for me

```
for?\(.*;.*;.*\).*\s*.*\s*.*\s*for?\(.*;.*;.*\)
```

matches your both your for loop constructs.

The problem here: if "somecode" would be two lines, you need to **again** put another "line-content-matcher" entry into the regex.

I tried

```
for?\(.*;.*;.*\)(.*\s*)*for?\(.*;.*;.*\)
```

but at least for me, that crashes eclipse.

(which doesn't come as surprise, as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) makes it clear that "counting", aka "indefinite" structure can not work with regular expressions)

Comment: .*?; is not the issue. for?\(.*?;.*?;.*?\) is searching perfectly. issue is i want to search two for loops. In between can be anything including newline.

Comment: I found some kind of solution; I hope it is helpful enough for you to accept my answer and reward the time I put in here ;-)

Comment: and yes it crashes eclipse. :P